# How to fill a WPF Datagrid but not directly from the DB using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have been banging my head against a wall for a while on this one.  I'm trying to fill a WPF datagrid from a mysql database using C# .net.  The problem is that I need to modify the data before sticking it into the datagrid because the data is not in the right format.  The only examples I can find when searching is how to automatically stick the data from the query directly into the database.

Here is what my current table from mysql looks like.

```
1   0456    clockin         5/14/2013 8:36:26 AM
2   0456    breakout    5/14/2013 8:36:39 AM
3   0456    breakin     5/14/2013 8:36:40 AM
4   0456    clockout    5/14/2013 8:36:41 AM
5   0456    clockin         5/14/2013 8:37:14 AM
6   0456    breakout    5/14/2013 8:50:27 AM
7   0456    breakin     5/14/2013 8:50:34 AM
```

Now I need to take out all the punches for the week(5/12 - 5/18) with the given userID(0456).  Then I need to stick those values into a datagrid that is set up with the seven days of the week.  So under each day it would list all the punches(clockin, breakout, etc) with their associated times.

Edit: tnw asked for code.  Here is my XML for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="253" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="219,208,0,0" Name="weekHours" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="556" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" Focusable="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Action" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sun" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mon" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tue" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wed" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Thu" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fri" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sat" Width="65"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And then for the code behind, this is all I can find on how to fill a Datagrid.

```
public void FillDataGrid(String query, DataGrid dg)
    {
        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dg.DataContext = dt;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  I am brand new to C# and .net.  Maybe I should not even be using a datagrid for this.
Thanks
Mike

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried?

Comment: I discourage the use of `System.Data` in WPF client-side. Create a proper data model and use an ORM, or at least a `Micro-ORM` instaed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a view model that is bound to your `DataGrid`. When you have loaded the data from database, iterate through the records and create a view model.
The following snippet shows a way how you could solve your problem:

MyViewModel.cs:

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }
      public int Punches { get; set; }
      public int UserId { get; set; }
 }
```

Here you bind the data to the DataGrid:

```
 var viewModels = new List<MyViewModel>();

 foreach(var item in dt.Rows)
 {
      var vm = new MyViewModel();
      vm.UserId = item["UserId"];
      vm.Punches = item["Punches"];
      vm.Date = DateTime.Parse(item["Date"]);
      //....
      viewModels.Add(vm);
 }
 dg.DataContext = viewModels;
```

This is a common pattern if you work with WPF and maybe with MVVM. A view model contains the actual data but optionally modified for better displaying in the view (here your `DataGrid`).
If you do some research, you will notice, that mostly a view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for change tracking. Your view model could also implement this interface, if you want to react when the user modifies something in the `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ListView - GridView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourData}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!-- The columns here -->
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In your code you will create a property (or as you like to do it) which is `IEnumerable` and you can databind with it. Otherwise you can set the `Datasource` property of the grid.